# Como elimino un Objeto de Arraylist pidiéndolo por teclado?

Tags: java

```
        Producto p = new Producto("Leche", 2);
        Producto p1 = new Producto("Pan", 1);
        Producto p2 = new Producto("Huevos",12);
        Producto p3 = new Producto("Arroz",3);
        Producto p4 = new Producto("Ketchup",1);

        ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        // añadimos los 5 objetos al Arraylist.
        lista.add(p);
        lista.add(p1);
        lista.add(p2);
        lista.add(p3);
        lista.add(p4);
```

Tengo estos objetos añadidos en el Arraylist y lo que intento es eliminar uno de ellos de esta manera.
Me pregunta por consola : Que producto quieres eliminar?
y yo poner Pan/pan con ignoreCase y se me elimine el objeto pan que seria p1.

```
                    String produc;
                    int indice = 0;
                    System.out.println("Producto a eliminar: ");
                    produc = sc.next();
                    indice = lista.indexOf(produc);

                    if (indice != -1){
                        lista.remove(indice);
                        System.out.println("Producto eliminado");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Producto no encontrado");
                    }
```

He probado con esto pero no me funciona...

Comment: Tu lista no contiene strings.. contiene objetos del tipo producto.. vos tenes que buscar no un indice magico, si no recorrer la lista y buscar el objeto que queres, para poder eliminarlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si aun no lo haces, debes de encapsular los campos de la clase `Productos` (getters y setters) para poder acceder a sus valores.

Luego como indica @gbianchi debes de recorrer la lista en busca del producto; en este caso por el campo `nombre`, encontrar el producto, por ende la posición y borrar el elemento.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
  if (lista.get(i).getNombre() != null && lista.get(i).getNombre().contains(search)) {
    lista.remove(i)
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow Gracias! Si los getters y setter si que los hago. Me gustaria saber por que lista.get(i) eso que hace? y .constains?

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar documentación oficial de java para esos métodos: [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) y [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))